# Entity Framework - Select Single Column with Null Check

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Trying below query to select value from single column in Entity Framework, but it is throwing exception when **ColumnA** is having Null value.

```
string test = dbContext.TABLE.Where(p => p.A== A).Select(x => x.ColumnA).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

I want to select some default value or assign null to string test if ColumnA is Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using C# 6.0 or higher Use the `?.` operator:

```
string test = dbContext.TABLE.SingleOrDefault(p => p.A == A)?.ColumnA.ToString();
```

If prior to C# 6.0 you can:

```
var columnA = dbContext.TABLE.Where(p => p.A == A).Select(x => x.ColumnA).SingleOrDefault();
string test = columnA == null ? null : columnA.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Feel the exception was because I was trying toString() before null check.

Comment: @PradeepHegde - exactly -  `ToString()` on a `null` results in an exception :)